# Google Website Optimizer Validation Warning

Tags: web, google-website-optimizer

I have been using Google website optimizer(GWO) to run a multivariate test on my web page. When I either do offline or online validation, I receive a warning stating there is multiple occurrences of my page sections. For example, if one of my page sections was Description Changes, optimizer would say I have two or more occurrences of that script.

I have gone through and checked through my code and have no duplicated any of the page section scripts. Even though GWO states that are multiple occurrences I can still create the experiment.

Does anyone know how to fix multiple occurrences from happening or if there are multiple occurrences if it affects the results.

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you provide a link to the page in question

Comment: Hi yc,

Right now the page is offline because I didn't want it to be posted if multiple occurrences cause problems in running the experiment. I also don't have the ability to post it to a live server. The validation problem occurs on step 2 of the Google Website Multivariate test. The page asks you to install the control and tracking script along with your page section scripts. After doing this, offline validation shows two occurrences.

Comment: just post the relavent sections of source code to pastebin.com or something, it's impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Sorry to get back to you so late but I was not going to receive enough traffic to run a multivariate test. I am now running two A/B tests.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but the issue might be that you have a latin-1 character set:

See the following post in the google forums:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/websiteoptimizer/thread?tid=70b4938cf4de24f2&hl=en